# Remote validation asp.net and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-validation

I am trying to get my double validation working and I seriously have no clue why it does not work.

My model is following:

```
[Required]
[Remote("CheckForHourRange", "Bookings")]
public double ReservationLength { get; set; }
```

So far so good right?
Looking at the controller it is following:

```
public JsonResult CheckForHourRange(double hours)
    { 
            var integerPart = Math.Truncate(hours);
            var fractionalPart = hours - Math.Truncate(hours);
            double fractionalDigits = fractionalPart.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Length;

            if (integerPart <= 14 && fractionalDigits <= 1)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            if (hours <= 0)
            {
                return Json("The length can't be less or equal to 0", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            if (integerPart > 14)
            {
                return Json("Sorry, we are open from 10.00 to 00.00, thus the hours can't be more than 14", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            if (integerPart <= 14 && fractionalDigits > 1)
            {
                return Json("Sorry, the hour must be only one place after comma", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

As soon as I try to run the code Ill get the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'hours' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult CheckForHourRange(Double)' in 'Web.Controllers.BookingsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Parameter name: parameters

I have debugged it and I understand that the controller does not run the validation part, which is strange because this one works.

```
 [Required, Range(1, 30, ErrorMessage = "The table number must be between 1 and 30")]
 [Remote("CheckForTableExist", "Tables")]
 public int TableNumber { get; set; }

 public JsonResult CheckForTableExist(int TableNumber)

    {
        var data = _uow.Tables.All.FirstOrDefault(a => a.TableNumber.Equals(TableNumber));

        if (data != null)
        {
            return Json("Sorry, this number of table already exists", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I am sure this has nothing to do with map routing because I haven't changed it.

Hoping for your help!~

**I agree that this was an edit, I'll just add the controller here, if someone else needs it some day**

```
public JsonResult CheckForHourRange(double reservationLength)
    {
        var integerPart = 0;
        var fractionalPart = 0;
        string s = reservationLength.ToString();
        string[] parts = s.Split('.');
        try
        {
            integerPart = (int) Convert.ToDouble(parts[0]);
            fractionalPart = (int) Convert.ToDouble(parts[1]);
        }
        catch { }

        var fractionalDigits = fractionalPart.ToString().Length;


        if (!(integerPart >= 0)) return Json("Hours cannot be negative", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (fractionalDigits > 2)
        {
            return Json("Sorry, there cannot be more than one number after comma", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        if (integerPart == 0)
        {
            return fractionalDigits > 1 ? Json("Sorry, there cannot be more than one number after comma", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        if (!(integerPart >= 14))
            return fractionalDigits > 1
                ? Json("Sorry, there cannot be more than one number after comma", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
                : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (integerPart != 14)
            return
                Json(
                    "Sorry, we are open from 10:00 to 00:00, thus we are open 14 hours, therefore enter correct value",
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return fractionalDigits > 0 ? Json("Sorry, we are open from 10:00 to 00:00, thus we are open 14 hours, therefore enter correct value", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: change your method signature as `public JsonResult CheckForHourRange(double? ReservationLength )`

Comment: Well, this is broken as well, due to math.truncate cant convert from double? to decimal

Comment: Well..omit `?` just try this `public JsonResult CheckForHourRange(double ReservationLength)`

Comment: Figured that out myself. Thank you!!
Even though there is a error within the logic, basic validation now works.
LIFE SAVER!